# HTML anchor tag append id name

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, anchor

I link to the different section on the same page using anchor tag, each time it appends the id to end of url,i don't want id name to the end of url, 
my code look like this-

```
<div id="parallax-bg4">
    <a ="#"><img id="bg4-1" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/images/parallax/signup.png"></a>
</div>
```

I write the anchor tag on id="b4-1"

```
<a name="bg4-1"></a>
```

And write the jQuery on same id for focusing the input text box.

```
$(function(){
    $("#bg4-1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#id_email').focus();
  });
});
```

Some time it works,but most of the time i need to double click on image.i also remove the event.preventDefault() but it still not work.

Comment: It works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/caLq9/.

Comment: @null, It's not working properly, for that i need to double click on chrome browser.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? It only takes one click for me.

Comment: @null, it is Version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: @Tushar.PUCSD the latest Chrome is **Version 32.0.1700.107**

Comment: Any reason you're not using `<label>`?

Comment: @Bart - Input text box and submit button come from launchrocket.co, i just integrate it with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('a[name=bg4-1]').click(function () {});
```